# Still curious about memory management in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management

In a class derived from UIViewController there is a message implementation that is accessing derived property `view` like this:

```
- (void) doSomethingOnView
{
  MyView *v = (MyView *) [self view];
  [v doOnView:YES];
  [v release];
}
```

According to quick documentation on property view of UIView it is a nonatomic read-write property in retain mode. My books here (e.g. "Beginning iPhone 4 Development" by Mark, Nutting, LaMarche) are reading that on reading properties in retain mode a release on obtained reference is required.

But my analyzer complains the `[v release]` with "Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller". Where is my fault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first line, `MyView *v` is just a pointer that is being set to point to a property already owned by your `UIViewControllwer`. You `UIViewController` has it through inheritence. It is declared elsewhere, not by you, therefore it is not `alloc`ed by you.

When you set a pointer to point to an object which you never explicitly `alloc`ed or `retain`ed, you don't need to `release` it, because you never increased its reference count. [Read more here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) if you are curious.

So the point is, don't call `[v release];`.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, finally had a look inside Apple's Memory Management Policies document and it's actually explaining the issue in a very clear way. I'm somewhat sorry for that question ...

Comment: @soletan: No problem. Yes, remember that official documentation is your friend as well.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code:

```
self.view = anotherView;
```

Then if `view`is a property which is declared as `retain`, `anotherView` will be implicitly retained.

This works when you are assigning a variable.

In your code:

1. You are not using properties (i.e. the dot notation)
2. You are not assigning any variable

   You try to release something you did not allocate yourself with alloc for instance

Try reading the [Declared Properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html) and [Memory management guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) sections of Apple's Objective-C documentation again if that is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't `alloc` the view, so you do not need to release it.

Where in the book are you reading that a release is needed in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I think you misinterpreted what the book says. if you provide a quote we can explain it to you further.

In this case, you don't need to release cause there were no `alloc` or `retain` sent to v.